¿Cómo configurar el dominio de wildfy?
Estoy teniendo problemas con el dominio de wildfly lo que quiero hacer es unir un servidor esclavo pero no me sale nada de lo que hago me puede guiar

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! intenta agregar mas informacion a tu pregunta, como que cosas intentaste y que errores recibiste...

a menos que sean problemas emocionales, compártenos el mensaje de error o el comportamiento derivado de esos problemas
